# discerning between "metaphor" and" symbol"

Tags: figures-of-speech

I am wondering if symbol and metaphor could be considered interchangeable-- And, when they cannot. Or, would you please show me an authoratative source?

Any comment or feed back would greatly be appreciated

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1173/is-there-a-fine-line-between-symbolism-and-metaphors-in-literature

Comment: This may be an interesting question but it is too broad and the differences can be easily understood looking the terms in a dictionary. Please explain what  specifically you don't understand or is unclear about the two terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they're not interchangable.

See these entries on vocabulary.com and note the example usages:

- [symbolic](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/symbolic)
- [symbolism](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/symbolism)
- [metaphor](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/metaphor)

---

A metaphor is an analogy between two different things. A symbol is simply a representation of something.

The key difference here is that something can be a symbol without being a metaphor. A handshake could be a symbolic gesture of friendship. You wouldn't call a handshake a metaphor.